# Pygame waiting the user to keypress a key

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, keypress

I am searching a method, where the program stops and waiting for a spesific key to be pressed by the user. May I can implement this one with a while loop? I need the best algorithm, if there exist a build-in function of waiting, to avoid the loop. 
I found several information on the [official website of pygame](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html), but nothing help.

Here is a testing algorithms but won't work:

```
key = "f"
while key != "K_f":
     key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
     if key[Keys.K_f]:
         do something...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it with a while loop and an event queue:

```
from pygame.locals import *
def wait():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_f:
                return
```

Comment: Cheers. Looks nice, but I get error for the if statment with the `K_f`. I Change it to: `if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == K_f:` 
But i get the following error: `NameError: name 'K_f' is not defined` so I try to change it into `... = pygame.K_f` but now, is like the if statment not get true when I press the f key.

Comment: I just checked, it works for me, as to the NameErrors, I forgot to include `from pygame import *` at the top, you can leave it with the `pygame.` prefix. Try printing the event.key on a KEYDOWN event to see what you are pressing at the moment. Maybe it's a keyboard issue.

Comment: AFAIK, attributes in each event type are different. So, the event shall not always have `key` attribute. For example, calling event.key will be an error for the MOUSEMOTION event.

Answer (score 8):

If you are waiting for a key to be pressed you can use the event.wait() function.  This is useful, because it does not require a-lot of processing.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.event.clear()
while True:
    event = pygame.event.wait()
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key = K_f:
            do something...
```

Note that event.wait() waits for events to appear in the event cache, the event cache should be cleared first.

[pygame.event documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)

Comment: This is good, except maybe in cases where very accurate event time stamps are needed.