# pygame.event.wait() in pygame python library eats up 100%CPU

Tags: python, pygame

I use pygame.event.wait() function in script to lower down CPU usage.
I found this idea here:

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.wait

and example of usage here:
[Pygame waiting the user to keypress a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748326/pygame-waiting-the-user-to-keypress-a-key)

I am trying to figure out why the function is not working as intended and where is the error in the script:

```
import pygame    
from pygame.locals import *    
import threading    


def read_keyboard():    
  pygame.event.clear()    
  while True:    
    event = pygame.event.wait()     # here we wait until user hits keyboard     
    player_input = ''     
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)    
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:    
      if event.unicode == 'h':    
      player_input = 'hello'     
    elif event.type == QUIT:    
      return     

read_keyboard_thread = threading.Thread(target = read_keyboard)

pygame.init()                       
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((480,360))                       
read_keyboard_thread.start()
```

Comment: "not working as intended" what's the actual issue?

Comment: the issue is that once I start the application, it consumes 100% CPU

Comment: yes. Did that. It does. But I am not sure this is how it should work. If I remove wait(), I get the same result CPU usage 100%

Comment: do you get a zillion print statements, or just one by keypress?

Comment: 2 by keypress. one print before wait and one after it

Comment: the 100% cpu is probably somewhere else, then. Try _not_ to start the thread, I'm sure you're still getting it.

Comment: it is a good idea, but the posted script is actually the whole application..)). I tried to remove as much as possible, but no luck. It is as if pygame itself is the reason. I even added sleep(2) into while loop, but it still didn't work out..... Guess one of the solutions is to try out a different library

Comment: starting a thread and not using `join` in the end sometimes confuses interpreters. Try to add `read_keyboard_thread.join()` at the end (not very useful to use threads now :))

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the issue was caused by how sound is handled in pygame. It appears that CPU utilization is a know issue with pygame and there are different posts about it, particularly this one helped to solve the issue:

https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/331

I updated the code to disable some mixer class in pygame and it helped. I am lucky not to need sound in this project :-)

```
 53 pygame.init()    #  here we start all of the pygame stuff
 54 pygame.mixer.quit()
```

Finally, there are recommendations to compile pygame from source to solve the issue if mixer is needed

https://github.com/pygame/pygame